# Python - tempfile.TemporaryFile cannot be read; why?

Tags: python, file, io, temporary-files

The [official documentation for TemporaryFile](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) reads:

> The mode parameter defaults to 'w+b'
>   so that the file created **can be read
>   and written without being closed**.

Yet, the below code does not work as expected:

```
import tempfile

def play_with_fd():
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as f:
        f.write('test data\n')
        f.write('most test data\n')

        print 'READ:', f.read()

        f.write('further data')

        print 'READ:', f.read()

        f.write('even more')
        print 'READ:', f.read()

        print 'READ:', f.read()
        print 'READ:', f.read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    play_with_fd()
```

The output I get is:

```
> python play.py 
READ: 
READ: 
READ: 
READ: 
READ:
```

Can anyone explain this behavior? Is there a way to read from temporary files at all? (without having to use the low-level mkstemp that wouldn't automatically delete the files; and I don't care about named files)

Comment: Using a `flush` did not help.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You must put

```
f.seek(0)
```

before trying to read the file (this will send you to the beginning of the file), and

```
f.seek(0, 2)
```

to return to the end so you can assure you won't overwrite it.

Comment: Instead of `f.seek(0, 2)` I'd use `f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)`

Comment: Was so confused why I couldn't `read()` anything, started messing with `delete=True` and `try...finally: os.remove()`... all because I forgot about `os.seek()`! Saved me 10 ugly lines of code

Answer (score 7):

`read()` does not return anything because you are at the end of the file. You need to call [`seek()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) first before `read()` will return anything. For example, put this line in front of the first `read()`:

```
f.seek(-10, 1)
```

Of course, before writing again, be sure to `seek()` to the end (if that is where you want to continue writing to).